# Can't resize partitions in Ubuntu

Tags: gparted, disk-management

I can't resize or move `/dev/sda5` which has kali installed on it. An error pops up every time. I am using GParted in Ubuntu and trying to resize this partition. Basically I want to resize `/dev/sda4`, on which Ubuntu is installed.

[image]

Comment: What error pops up ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) From the second answer: *In order to expand the ... [48GiB sda4] ... partition, you must have free space in front of or after it.*

Answer (score 5):

You cannot resize the `/dev/sda4` partition, because it contains the mounted running system. *What you're trying to do there is like having a surgeon operate on himself at home...*  **;-)**

You have to do the resizing action from a live media - boot from an Ubuntu installation media. Select Try Ubuntu without installing and once on the Live desktop environment open GParted.

Now you will find all partitions (except of `swap` eventually) unmounted and are able to resize partitions. In case the `swap` partition is mounted, right-click the partition and select 'swapoff'. This is the recommended and safe way to work on disks/partitions without damaging systems.

*(Which would be the equivalent of going to the hospital and have the surgeon operate on you there)*

Comment: OP asked about resizing /dev/sda5, to make room for growing /dev/sda4 later.

Comment: @SorenA Working on a disk with mounted partitions is definitely not recommended. Too many things may go badly wrong, chances are that operating systems will be unbootable, so perform everything from a live media. :)

Comment: /dev/sda5 is not mounted as far as I can see ..

Comment: @SorenA Yes, I can see the same ... nevertheless - working on disks and partitions from within a running system is generally not recommended. And when OP says "Basically I want to resize dev/sda4 partition", this has to be done from a live media. :)

Comment: I see no problems working on unmounted partitions or disks, you really can't make any errors in gparted that you can't do in a live-usb booted scenario. Professionally we do it all the time, because we can't afford the down-time.

Comment: @SorenA cl-netbox is absolutely correct. You don't use gparted to manage live file systems. "Professionally" I just wouldn't do it. It's like trying to change spark plugs in a running automobile motor... could you do it... sure... but you might get burned.

Comment: @SorenA It's true. I tried to resize Windows from Windows once and destroyed the system. The same is likely true for Ubuntu.